# parsing a path into a nested html list with javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, tree, nested-lists

I have multiple path strings (One for each leaf node) such as

> item1
>
> item2
>
> Folder with some children / Sub-item 3.1
>
> Folder with some children / Sub-item 3.2
>
> Document with some children / Sub-item 4.1
>
> Document with some children / Sub-item 4.2

Where item 1,item 2, Sub-item 3.1,3.2,4.1, and 4.2 are leaf nodes; And what I want to do is build a nested HTML like this:

```
  <ul>
        <li>item1
        <li>item2
        <li>Folder with some children
            <ul>
                <li>Sub-item 3.1
                <li>Sub-item 3.2
            </ul>

        <li>Document with some children
            <ul>
                <li>Sub-item 4.1
                <li>Sub-item 4.2
            </ul>
    </ul>
```

Or a JSON object like this:

```
[
     {title: "Item 1"},
     {title: "Item 2"},
     {title: "Folder with some children",
         children: [
             {title: "Sub-item 3.1"},
             {title: "Sub-item 3.2"}
         ]
     },
     {title: "Document with some children",
         children: [
             {title: "Sub-item 4.1"},
             {title: "Sub-item 4.2"}
         ]
     }
]
```

But I'm having a hard time doing this. I've spent 10 hours on this to no avail. I'm open to using jquery. Please can you guide me in the right direction? My javascript is still not good enough to do these things on the fly.

Comment: You mentioned that they are leaf nodes. What type of tree structure are you using to store them currently?

Comment: @Matthew As I mentioned in the first line, currently they are a list of strings. the string represents a path. the last token of that path is the leaf node, and the rest are directories :)

Comment: `I have multiple path strings (One for each leaf node) such as`you never mentioned that they were in a `list of strings`. That was the reason I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the best way to do this was to build the html elements using javascript's createElement and a recursive function and just append it to the DOM in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to research into "recursive functions", it should give you a good start into the techniques useful for this sort of problem.

Comment: I know of recursive functions, my problem was in the way javascript handled document.write; It didn't work like a regular outputstream

Comment: I see no worries @mrBorna, glad you foudn a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in jQuery, but maybe this could help. I developed this after seeking the web and found no solution.

http://www.chapleau.info/article/ArrayofUrlsToASitemap.html